# How do I compile and link multiple files from the command line?

Tags: c++, cygwin

I used to use visual studio as a compiler for C++. I have been recently using g++ in cygwin. My problem is I donot know how to use cygwin for inheritance. The code below is just for illustration, to make my question more clearer.

Base class:

```
// A.h:
class A{
void func1();
};
class B:A{
func2();
};

//-------------
//A.cpp:
#include"A.h";
A::func1(){
};
//-----------

//B.cpp:
#include"A.h";
B::func2(){
func1();
};

int main(){
B b.
b.func2();
return 0;}
//----------------
```

I run (similar to ) this without any problem in visual studio. But I do not know how to run it in cygwin. How to include A.h , A.cpp, to run main() in B.cpp.

Comment: So, basically, you are asking "How do I put together a command-line to the compiler to build my code?" - which is quite a different subject title than you have given it, but I believe that would be what you are asking, although I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: Research the following:  *g++*, *makefile*, and *gdb*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to compile your class implementation files into object files first, then link them.

If you were to use the [g++ compiler](http://linux.die.net/man/1/g++), you could run these commands...

1. `g++ -c A.cpp`
2. `g++ -c B.cpp`
3. `g++  A.o B.o main.cpp -o my_program`

This can be automated with a [Makefile](http://www.opussoftware.com/tutorial/TutMakefile.htm), so you don't have to type everything out. As others have mentioned [GDB](http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/) can also be used for debugging, but you need to add the '-g' option to your compiler flags to created debugging symbols.

Also, you have a period at the end of line 1 of your main function, rather than a semi-colon.

Comment: I edited my mistake, thank you. Can I ask you what "my_program" is for?

Comment: The '-o' option specifies an output name. Otherwise, it will use the default name of 'a.out'. Checkout the g++ man page for other debugging / optimization flags that you can use.

Answer (score 0):

Learn about makefiles... or type this in command line

```
g++ -Wall -c -g -o A.o A.cpp
g++ -Wall -c -g -o B.o B.cpp
g++ -o myProgram.exe A.o B.o
```

You need to compile both cpp files to object files, then link them together. 
I expect you use g++ and it's in PATH.

Note:

- I used -g to generate "debug" files
- I used -Wall to show all warnings (golden rule : fix warnings)